# ListView doesn't show the actual video files after scroll down

Tags: listview, android-videoview, android-cursor

In my app, I am showing the SD card videos in the ListView. ListView shows Video Thumbnails, Title, Size, Duration. When I scroll down It shows the same videos and thumbnails but If I click on an item it shows the different video file to another activity. I just want that in the ListView Where actual video will show whether I scroll down or up.

Here is my code.

public class LoadVideo extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Cursor videoCursor;
private int video_column_index;
ListView videoList;
int count;
String[] thumbColumns = {MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA,
        MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.load_video_activity);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    init_phone_video_grid();
}

private void init_phone_video_grid()
{
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION};

    videoCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);
    count = videoCursor.getCount();

    videoList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.videoList);
    videoList.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(this.getApplicationContext()));
    videoList.setOnItemClickListener(videoGridListener);
}

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener videoGridListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        video_column_index = videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        videoCursor.moveToPosition(i);
        String fileName = videoCursor.getString(video_column_index);
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoadVideo.this, ShowVideo.class);
        intent.putExtra("videofilename", fileName);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};

public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;

    VideoAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        String id;

        if (view == null)
        {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_items, viewGroup, false);

            viewHolder.titleName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);
            viewHolder.size = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.size);
            viewHolder.thumbImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageIcon);

            //Title
            video_column_index = videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            videoCursor.moveToPosition(i);
            id = videoCursor.getString(video_column_index);
            viewHolder.titleName.setText(id);

            //Size
            video_column_index = videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);
            videoCursor.moveToPosition(i);

            String vSize;
            long videoSize = videoCursor.getLong(video_column_index);
            double actualSizeInMB = videoSize/(1024.0 * 1024.0);
            DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

            if (actualSizeInMB > 1)
            {
                vSize = dec.format(actualSizeInMB).concat(" MB");
                viewHolder.size.setText(vSize);
            }
            else
            {
                vSize = dec.format(actualSizeInMB).concat(" KB");
                viewHolder.size.setText(vSize);
            }

            //Duration
            video_column_index = videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
            videoCursor.moveToPosition(i);
            long  time = videoCursor.getLong(video_column_index);
            long seconds = time/1000;
            long minutes = seconds/60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            String setTime ;
            if (seconds < 10)
            {
                setTime = String.valueOf(minutes) + ":0" + String.valueOf(seconds);
                viewHolder.duration.setText(setTime.concat( " | "));
            }
            else
            {
                setTime = String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds);
                viewHolder.duration.setText(setTime.concat( " | "));
            }

            //String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID, MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
            //Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,
                    //MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", new String[] { id }, null);
            //cursor.moveToFirst();
            //long ids = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));

            long ids = videoCursor.getInt(videoCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
            ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 1;
            Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, ids, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
            viewHolder.thumbImage.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
            curThumb = null;

            //video_column_index = videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            //videoCursor.moveToPosition(i);
            //String path = videoCursor.getString(video_column_index);
            //Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
            //viewHolder.thumbImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

            //videoThumbnailCursor.close();

        }

        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView titleName;
        TextView size;
        TextView duration;
        ImageView thumbImage;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you also seeing duplicate thumbnails/data?

Comment: exactly first 6 or 7 items are actual then everything is same as before. Could you please tell me why this is happening? @Hahn

Comment: The problem is that you are setting all the data/image ONLY when the view is null. When you scroll, the views that are already created are recycled, so in those cases, the view is NOT null, but in the above code, you weren't doing anything if a view is not null. I have posted an answer, let me know if it's clear

Comment: yes, It worked. thank you @Hahn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this point: `if(view == null)`, modify your code like:

```
if (view == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_items, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder.titleName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        viewHolder.size = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.size);
        viewHolder.thumbImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageIcon);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);

 } else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)(view.getTag());
 }
//Title.....and so on...
```